# Calculate the speed of an object that has travelled a given distance in a given amount of time

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a problem for my Introduction to Programming class and I am having a hard time. I am very new to programming/Python and would be appreciative of any help I can get.

Here's my problem: Calculate the speed of an object that has travelled a given distance in a given amount of time.  (distance = rate * time).  Distances could be measured in meters, feet, miles or light years.  Times could be measured in seconds, hours or years.  The speed should be reported in meters per second (m/s).  You should report any input errors.

Here's what I have so far:

```
distance = raw_input("Enter the distance (meters, feet, miles, or light years):  ")
time = raw_input("Enter the time (seconds, hours, or years):  ")
rate = raw_input("Enter the rate):  ")

distancee = rate * time
```

I'm not very sure of how to convert given units of measurement. Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: You should at least have a suffix to indicate unit... For example:
If raw input is '10 meters', you can split it then use the second part ('meters' in this case to indicate the unit)

Comment: To start things off. You want to cast things to an int. Example: `int(raw_input("Enter the distance (meters, feet, miles, or light years):  "))`. After that, things get a bit unclear. As Akash1993 is mentioning, you should review how you are handling this data and the units you are using.

Comment: Think about it like this, if you buy something and the price-tag does not mention 'Dollars' or 'cents', what would be the first question that pops up in your mind? 'Dollars or cents?' ... Right? For programming also you have to specify it somehow, just raw value won't work if you are accepting multiple units.

Comment: thanks for the feedback guys, I really appreciate it. However, I'm still a bit confused. What do you mean by "split" and how would I handle different units and time? this is all so confusing for me, I'm sorry

Comment: Don't bother with splitting, ask them the units as a separate question.

Comment: Yes, if you are unsure about split and how it works, better to take @Barmar's suggestion and ask them units as a separate question.